# Joining and combining two tables that have the same ID for different rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

In SQLite I have two tables, `tab_a` and `tab_b`. Both have some similar columns and some that differ:

```
tab_a -> id | utc | name | data_1 | data_2 | data_3
tab_b -> id | utc | name | data_x | data_y | data_x
```

So in this example both tables have the columns `id`, `utc`, `name` and three other columns that are specific to those respective tables. Moreover, the `id` field in both tables can contain the same values. However, they are not the same data sets! So for example `id = 1` in `tab_a` is another data set than `id = 1` in `tab_b` - they just randomly have the same ID.

Now I want to (outer?) join these two tables to get a combined list of all records from both of them, of course only with the shared columns. But since the IDs of both tables can be the same, I need an additional column in my join to tell what table this row comes from.

So for example the joined result could look like this:

```
id | tab   | utc  | name
---+-------+------+-----
 1 | tab_a | ...  | ...
 2 | tab_a | ...  | ...
 2 | tab_b | ...  | ...
 3 | tab_b | ...  | ...
 4 | tab_a | ...  | ...
 4 | tab_b | ...  | ...
```

How can I join two tables in SQLite this way and add this "custom" column? If that is not possible, what other "best practice" approach should I use in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `UNION`, not `JOIN` for your purposes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_a (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    utc text,
    name text
);
CREATE TABLE tab_b (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    utc text,
    name text
);

INSERT INTO tab_a (id, utc, name)
VALUES (1, "utc1", "name1"), (2, "utc2", "name2");

INSERT INTO tab_b (id, utc, name)
VALUES (1, "utc3", "name3"), (2, "utc4", "name4");

SELECT id, name, utc, "tab_a" as tab from tab_a
UNION SELECT id, name, utc, "tab_b" as tab from tab_b;
```

Response:

| id | name | utc | tab |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | utc1 | tab_a |
| 1 | name3 | utc3 | tab_b |
| 2 | name2 | utc2 | tab_a |
| 2 | name4 | utc4 | tab_b |

[Example in DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j3FXo7S7BbQRYXvXyyS6Dn/0)